# AWS Glue job accessing parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I have a glue job (Spark job) written in Scala and I would like to pass parameters into it. I use lambda function for triggering job. How should I access parameters passed into job?

Is this the proper way?

```
def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {

    /** This is input parameter */
   val par = sysArgs(0)

}
```

Or some other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [GlueArgParser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-etl-scala-apis-glue-util-glueargparser.html) to resolve parameters:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser

val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(
  sysArgs, Array(
    "JOB_NAME",
    "CUSTOM_PARAMETER")
)
val param = args("CUSTOM_PARAMETER")
```

Please note, parameters should be passed with prefix `--` (ie. `--CUSTOM_PARAMETER`)